# Pinescript Strategy Entry and Exit Across Multiple Symbols

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I'm new to Pine Script and I am building my first basic strategy. Is there any way to code a strategy that has a long entry in a certain symbol and else long exit in that symbol, and if not in that symbol then enter into a different symbol that is not on the chart? I am trying to code "under these conditons, enter into VTV. Otherwise, sell VTV and enter into VUG." However, I can't seem to find how to enter code that gives an entry point for another symbol that doesn't have bars on the chart. Does anyone know if this is possible? Thank you for any advice in advance

I did a bunch of reserach trying to find sources that show the answer, but I couldn't find any. I currently have SPY open as my main symbol in the chart because it has one of the first condtions I want the entry point to ensure is there, but I can change it to either VTV or VUG as that is what I want to be buying and selling. However, if I did change it to either one, I still don't know if it is possible to enter and exit on a symbol not on the chart. This is my current code that inputs the variables:

`// Create Indicators
VTV = request.security(symbol = "BATS:VTV", timeframe = "D", expression = ta.sma(close, 260))
VUG = request.security(symbol = "BATS:VUG", timeframe = "D", expression = ta.sma(close, 10))
shorterMA = ta.sma(close, 10) //for SPY
longerMA = ta.sma(close, 50)  //for SPY

// Specify crossover conditions
longCondition = ta.crossover(shorterSMA, longerSMA)
longCondition2 = ta.crossover(VUG, VTV)`

I plot them but I do not know how to say "buy VTV if these conditons met, otherwise sell and buy VUG"

Answer (score 0):

You can't place orders from a script that runs on one chart on another chart.

You can as you've mentioned, get data from another chart to your current chart, so you'll have to use this data and build 2 scripts - one for each chart from data you get from the other chart